# Sorting data to form a base64 stream of data

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, base64

If you have a file that contains data that, when sorted correctly, forms a base64 stream of data, how to sort it correctly? Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class PracticeFinalExam {
public static void sort(ArrayList<Byte> decoder){
    byte temp;

    if(decoder.size() > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < decoder.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; i < decoder.size() - i - 1; j++){
                if(decoder.get(i).compareTo(decoder.get(i+1)) > 0){
                    temp = decoder.get(i);
                    decoder.set(i, decoder.get(i+1));
                    decoder.set(i+1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("finalinput.txt"));
        ArrayList<Byte> random = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        while(input.hasNextByte()){
            random.add(input.nextByte());
        }
        input.close();

        System.out.println("Unsorted: " + random);
        sort(random);
        System.out.println("Sorted: " + random);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}

}
```

I got an output like this:

```
Unsorted: [84]
Sorted: [84]
```

There is more data than what the output says.

Comment: Please explain how "sorting" is supposed to "correct" *encoded* data.

Comment: I am re-arranging the data to be able to use it as bas364 encoded data.

Comment: @HankHill It looks like you are studying and this is a problem for your practice. You'd want to re-read the problem. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is for encoding binary data and is usually in sequence. If the stream is not guaranteed to be in a sequence then there is usually a header or equivalent that tells you what position in the sequence that particular stream belongs to.